# Игнорирование ключевого слова

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как можно проигнорировать множество ключевых слов `define, int, uint, float` если они идут в контексте функции?

Regex: `([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)\s*(\()(.*?)`

Тут пересекается ключевое слово `int` и имя функции `int`, то есть,

```
int(castmenegative(1)) - каст положительного значения в отрицательное
```

В том же случае `int(C.Println("Hello World!"))` может является именем существующей функции которая вызывает подрядную функцию `C.Println("Hello World!")`.

```
int (C.Println("Hello World!"))
```

Тут нужен какой-то регексп который будет при матчинге ключевых слов `define, int, uint и так далее` без дополнения выводить его в отдельную группу. А при матчинге любого другого словосочетания, к примеру `inted`, выводит в группу только для имени функции. Имя функции не может быть `int, uint` и т.д, чтоб это понять нужно вынести в отдельную группу.

Должна получится примерно такая структура:

```
Group 1: int - только для ключевых слов
Group 2: <none> - только для НЕ ключевых слов
Group 3: (
Group 4: <none>
```

Первая группа должна матчится только если ключевое слово равняется `int`, то есть это группу только для ключевых слов. 
Вторая группа должна матчится только если ключевое слово не равняется `int`, то есть группа для всего остального, к примеру `superfunc(), intfunc()`.

```
Group 1: <none> - только для ключевых слов
Group 2: superfunc - только для НЕ ключевых слов
Group 3: (
Group 4: <none>
```

Надеюсь как-то более менее внятно выразился :)

Comment: Не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос. Но на ум приходит лишь вариант с явным перечислением ключевых слов. Вот такой пример: https://regex101.com/r/Fpeu1i/3

Comment: @justcvb спасибо, это то что нужно)